# Defining bounds of a shift of a sequence through $max, min$ functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the subsequence $a_2, a_3, a_4,\ldots, a_{n + 1}$ is bounded above by $U$ and bounded below by $L$, then the sequence has $max(a_1, U)$ as an upper bound and $min(a_1, L)$ as a lower bound. Why do we use $a_1$ as a parameter of $min, max$ functions here instead of $a_2$?

If the subsequence $a_3, a_4, a_5,\ldots, a_{n + 2}$ is bounded above by $U$ and bounded below by $L$, then the sequence has $max(a_1, a_2, U)$ as an upper bound and $min(a_1, a_2, L)$ as a lower bound. Why do we need two $a_i$ parameters for $min, max$ functions this time?

These questions are my own curiosity. Just in case they look like I just copy-pasted my homework without any attempt at solving them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually missing one small part of your question to have it make sense.  I'll try to explain.

Let us have a sequence $a ... a_n$.  This sequence has $n + 1$ elements.  If $n$ is finite then there must be an upper bound $U$ and lower bound $L$.  Lets select k elements of $a$.  We now have a new sequence $b ... b_k$.  That has an upper bound $U_k$.  From this information we want to find $U$ from $U_k$.  There are $n - k$ elements that are not part of the subsequence $b$.  We know nothing about those elements.  We cannot say that any of those elements are less than $U_k$ but we cannot say they are greater either so $U$ can be any of the removed elements or $U_k$.  So we can say that $U = \max (c_1...c_k, U_k)$ where c is the sequence of elements removed from $a$.

A similar explanation can be made for the lower bound.  Basically what this argument says is that the upper bound of a sequence is the max the upper bound of some sub sequence and any elements of the sequence that we don't know.  <del>This only is true if the sequence is bounded and finite.</del>

For the above to be true the set of elements that was removed from $a$ must be finite.  There must exist some upper bound of any finite sequence however if $c$ is infinite then $\max (c_1...c_k, $U_k$)$ is not necessarily defined because $c$ may not have a max even if it is bounded above.

Comment: Thank you, very nice explanation. For context, [here's the question](http://s9.postimg.org/kah22p1sf/Capture111.png) and [here's the answer](http://s11.postimg.org/5us42ndir/Capture222.png) that inspired my questions. From the question it looks like the sequences are infinite. Also, in my book the sequences are considered to be always infinite. Can you, please, comment on that.

Comment: The language that is used here depends a fair bit on what you're doing is a kind of ambiguous.  I should have clarified the last sentance.  It's not technically correct.  It's fine if the sequence is infinite however it doesn't necessarily work if the set of removed elements is finite.